# Is this a valid proof for showing two continuous functions that coincide on the rationals, are in fact the same function?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am trying to prove the following, but I am unsure about a particular step in my proof. I am aware of other proofs for this statement, but I am trying to prove it in a specific way.

**Statement:**

" Suppose $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are two continuous functions such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in{}\mathbb{Q}$. Then $f=g$ everywhere."

**My proof:**

Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, for each $\epsilon>0$ choose respective $\delta_1,\delta_2>0$ that satisfy the continuity definition. Now define the following: $$\delta=\min(\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}).$$

Let $c\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ with $|x-c|<{}\delta{}.$ Consider the following:

$$|f(c)-g(c)|$$
$$=|f(c)-f(x)+f(x)-g(x)+g(x)-g(c)|$$
$$\le|f(c)-f(x)|+|f(x)-g(x)|+|g(x)-g(c)|$$
$$<|f(x)-g(x)|+2\epsilon{}$$

This holds for all $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta),$ so must hold for any $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap\mathbb{Q}\neq\emptyset,$ which would lower the upper bound to simply $2\epsilon$ (since $|f(x)-g(x)|=0$ on $(c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap\mathbb{Q}$). Since *that* is true for every $\epsilon>0$ we have that $|f(c)-g(c)|$ is forced to be $0$, hence $f(c)=g(c)$ for all irrational $c$. Hence $f=g$ everywhere.

my issue is with making the $|f(x)-g(x)|=0$ where $x$ is rational and in the aforementioned open interval. Since it's true for all $x$ in that range, surely we can lower the upper bound?

Comment: The statement holds for all $x \in (c - \delta , c + \delta)$, but you can't say that $|f(x) - g(x)| = 0$ unless $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. For clarity's sake I would start with $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and then the whole proof flows well

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is if $|f(c)-g(c)|<|f(x)-g(x)|+2\epsilon$ for all $x\in{}(c-\delta,c+\delta)$ then if one of those $x$ makes $|f(x)-g(x)|=0$ then $|f(c)-g(c)|<2\epsilon$

Comment: basically taking infimum over $x\in{}(c-\delta,c+\delta)$ on the inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have that continuity at points, so the $\varepsilon - \delta$ statements must be about the point under consideration. Here is how I would do it instead if I am not required to use $\varepsilon - \delta$ statements:

We know that $f,g$ are everywhere continuous, and $f|_\mathbb{Q} = g|_\mathbb{Q}$. Let $c$ be an irrational number, and let $a_n \subset \mathbb{Q}$ be a sequence that converges to $c$. Then we have the following:

\begin{equation}
f(c) - g(c) = \left(f(\lim_\limits{n} a_n)\right) - \left(g(\lim_\limits{n} a_n)\right) = \left(\lim_\limits{n} f(a_n)\right) - \left(\lim_\limits{n} g(a_n)\right) = \lim_\limits{n} \left(f(a_n) - g(a_n) \right) = \lim_\limits{n} 0 = 0.
\end{equation}

Since you are specifically trying to use the $\varepsilon - \delta$ approach, here is an alternative:

Let $c$ be an irrational number. Since $f,g$ are continuous at $c$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that the typical statements hold. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, there exists $p \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (c - \delta, c+ \delta)$. So then:

\begin{equation}
|f(c) - g(c)| \leq |f(c) - f(p)| + |f(p) - g(p)| + |g(p) - g(c)| < 2 \varepsilon
\end{equation}
since $|f(p) - g(p)| = 0$.

Comment: Thank you, you wrote what I had in mind, but somehow I managed to make an absolute mess of it and confused myself. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

That is not correct. Note that the $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$ interval is not a fixed interval, since $\delta$ depends upon $c$. So, when $\varepsilon$ gets smaller, then so does $\delta$ and therefore saying that $f=g$ on the interval $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$, as if it was a fixed interval, makes no sense.

If $h=f-g$, then $h$ is continuous and it is $0$ on the rationals. If $h(x_0)\ne0$ for some $x_0$, then there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, then $\bigl|f(x)-f(x_0)\bigr|<\bigl|f(x_0)\bigr|$, which implies that $f(x)\ne0$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Why does $\delta$ depend upon $x$? Surely it depends only on $c$ and $\epsilon$ no?

Comment: Could you suggest a better direction for the $\epsilon - \delta$ proof of this statement. I'm not at all asking for the full blown answer, just some guided hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it depends upon $c$. I've edited my answer.

Comment: but surely if $f=g$ for every irrational $c$ we are done?

Comment: Yes, but you did not prove that. I have added another paragrapha to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I'll have another crack at it.